# Automounting home directories using LDAP in ArchLinux

Tags: ldap, nfs, openldap, automount, autofs

I have managed to set up an OpenLDAP server that runs ArchLinux. I can now log in from the client (also ArchLinux) using the LDAP users.

Now i want to mount the home directories over the network... I assume I need autofs and NFS for this, but all guides I find use a package called AutofsLDAP which does not exist in Arch.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo "/home /etc/auto.home" >> /etc/auto.master
 echo "* -fstype=nfs,rw,nosuid,soft fs1:/home/&" > /etc/auto.home
```

After that you need to reload the autofs daemon, anyway i recommend to place the network home of users in a deffirent place of local home, because you try to create a local home under /home and your using autofs under /home, you will got an error

Comment: Do i not need a autofs.schema for LDAP?

Comment: no, in this way, you don't need any ldap schema

Comment: aha, i mount the whole /home folder on boot. is there any way to prevent sudo users from being able to browse through all users files?

Comment: this is other problem, i hate sudo, sorry :(